# Why doesn't TypeScript narrow based on checks using a variable key?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, type-narrowing

If I have code roughly like this:

```
const obj: Record<string, SomeType>;
if ("key" in obj) {
  const val: SomeType = obj["key"];
  void val;
}
```

the TypeScript compiler doesn't give me any grief about the type of `val`.

Likewise if I write code like:

```
const val = obj["key"];
if (val) {
  const val2: SomeType = val;
  void val2;
}
```

the TypeScript compiler knows that `val`/`val2` can't be `| undefined` inside the check.

**But** if I write code like:

```
let k = "key";
if (obj[k]) {
  const val: SomeType = obj[k];
  void val;
}
```

then TypeScript complains that `val: Sometype` could still be `| undefined`.

Even if I use a `const` in a situation somewhat similar to the last it stays unhappy:

```
(["a", "b", "c"]).forEach(_k => {
  const k = _k;
  if (obj[k]) {
    const val: SomeType = obj[k];
    //         ^^^ VSCode still thinks it could be `| undefined`!
  }
});
```

Why is this?

Comment: You've run into [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).  Currently when guarding a property access like `obj[key]`, the `key` must be of a single known literal type for it to work.  (The checker uses the *type* of the key and not its *identity*, and so it can't tell the difference between `obj[key1]` and `obj[key2]` if `key1` and `key2` are of the same type. So the only way that works as a guard is if that type is a known literal like `"key"`.) Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: At a higher level, you're basically running into Turning's halting problem here. The compiler can't find *every* case, so the language implementers have to pick some arbitrary line to say, "good enough." Your use case falls on one side of that line, but if it didn't, there'd be some other use case just a bit more complex that would.

Comment: @jcalz Haven't reviewed that #10530 thoroughly but that does seem to help, thanks! Maybe doesn't quite explain why `let k = "key"` does NOT work, but `const k = "key"` *does* but then again in a loop `const k = _k: "a" | "b" | "c"` does NOT again — seems a bit inconsistent and the pattern isn't 100% clear to me yet.

Comment: When you write `let k = "key"` the type of `k` is inferred as `string`, whereas when you do it for `const k = "key"` you get a type of `"key"`.  Does that clear things up?  Do you want me to write up my answer or do you still need time to review things before you can decide whether something's still missing? (edit: `const k = _k: "a" | "b" | "c"` isn't valid, right?   Maybe you meant `const k: "a" | "b" | "c" = _k` but I don't know what `_k` is.  I'm ignoring that I guess.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that good at reasoning with types, but in your third block, changing `k` to a `const` makes the types work:

```js
const k = "key";
if (obj[k]) {
  const val: string = obj[k];
  void val;
}
```

And this doesn't fix your issue, but you can assert that an array is `const` inline.
The fourth code block I can only make typecheck by adding an intermediate step:

```js
(["a", "b", "c"] as const).forEach(k => {
    const val = obj[k] as const
    if (val) {
      const narrowed_val: string = val;
    }
  });
```

Hope this helps you get on with whatever you're doing, but hopefully someone smarter with typescript reasoning can explain exactly what's going on.

n.b. I changed your `SomeType` to `string` to make it easier to work with in vscode.

Comment: thanks, yeah unfortunately these variants do work for some reason but not the others! it's more the loop itself I'm trying to fix, don't really need the `let k` one but it's still a mystery why it can't work.

Comment: I checked out the TS issue in jcalz' comment, but read the replies of this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51368

Comment: What do you mean by "read the replies"?  Can you be explicit about what you're trying to have us notice?

Comment: > Yeah, foo["bar"] used to not be narrowable. Now it is, but the larger issue of foo[keyVar] not narrowing (which is a much bigger can of worms, implementation-wise) is still present.

Taken from https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51368#issuecomment-1298764344

Comment: Yes ms/TS#10530 is where they're tracking the larger issue, even though the name of the issue is no longer applicable.  Not sure why they won't either change the name to reflect that, or close it in favor of a separate issue. So whenever I talk about the larger issue I have the fun of pointing people to ms/TS#10530 and then have to have this kind of additional conversation about how it really is the place to watch for updates on the larger issue despite the name.  So fun, whee.